# Как в Kotlin использовать элемент recyclerview в качестве кнопки

Tags: android, kotlin, recyclerview, onclicklistener, setonclicklistener

У меня есть код на java:

```
ArrayList<MainList> main_lists;
....
    public class MovieViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView textView;
    public MovieViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.desc);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int position = getAdapterPosition();

                Context context = v.getContext();
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, GenresActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("main_key", main_lists.get(position).getMovie());
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Пробую переписать его на Kotlin

```
val mainList = ArrayList<MainData>()
.....
    class MainViewHolder(item: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(item) {
    val binding = MainItemBinding.bind(item)
    fun bind(mainData: MainData) = with(binding){
        mainText.text = mainData.name
    }
    item.setOnClickListener(
    object : View.OnClickListener {
        override fun onClick(v: View) {
            val position: Int = getAdapterPosition()
            val context = v.context
            val intent = Intent(context, GenresActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("main_key", mainList.get(position).getMovie())
            context.startActivity(intent)
        }
    })
}
```

Возникают следующие проблемы:
метод `getAdapterPosition()` выделяется красным, `MainViewHolder` не видет список `mainList`

Answer (score 0):

Хороший способ это имплементировать View.OnClickListener и реализовать метод onClick. Это и будет нажатие на элемент

```
inner class ContactHolder(private val binding: ContactItemBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root), View.OnClickListener {

        private var nameTextView: TextView
        private var latestMessage: TextView
        private lateinit var _staffs: Staffs

        init {
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
            nameTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contact_name)
            latestMessage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.latest_message)
        }      

        fun bindMessage(staffs: Staffs) {
            binding.setVariable(BR.staffs, staffs)
            _staffs = staffs
          
        }

        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            

            var bundle = Bundle()
            bundle.putSerializable("user", _staffs)
            v?.findNavController()?.navigate(R.id.action_nav_contact_list_to_nav_chat, bundle)
            
        }
    }
```

По поводу видимости. А зачем?

Comment: по поводу видимости - мне неободимо, чтобы программа видела список mainList, так как при нажатии в Intent должна передаваться информация о том, по какому из элементов было произведено нажатие. Новая activity должна заскаться, получать данные о том, какой элемент списка был нажат и происводь действия, основываясь на этих данных

Comment: В приведённом коде это и организованно. Точно такую же задачу решает. Вместо Bundle можно юзать Intent.putExtra(key, value), и в новой активити доставать эти данные